# Creating random url link

Tags: php, url, hyperlink

I am working on a web page, and I want to create a a random new URL after clicking submit button.

such as; "  .com/mh2562"
How can I create a random URL?

thanks

Comment: use rand() function and get random value from it and create random link

Comment: use rand() function to create it, you can combine some crypto functions like md5() or crypt() as welll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unique link try this:

```
$strLink = "/".md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).".php";
```

DEMO : http://codepad.org/hyFV7MqD

Comment: @user3160355 : did you try this?

Comment: how can i open it without displaying ".php" on browser?

Comment: I just want like  this"/codepad.org/hyFV7MqD",creating random value an using it without ".php" -> "/codepad.org/hyFV7MqD"

Comment: Then you have to be use htaccess rewriterule. it is not related to this question you should open another question for this. :)  There are some google investigation you need first for this. useful links: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-basic-examples.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use random function and can append it

$newUrlData = rand($min,$max);